# Convert `c(x, y)` as function argument to `c("x", "y")` in R (rlang/tidyevaluation)

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I want to let users of my function enter variables in the tidyeval data-masking way i.e. `fun(x, c(y, z))` as opposed to `fun("x", c("y", "z"))`, but when they enter arguments like `c(y, z)`, I want to be able to use this as a character vector, like `c("y", "z")`.

I do have a seriously overkill workaround for working with column names. That is, I use `{{` in a `dpylr::select()` call and then extract the column names:

```
fun_overkill <- function(data, cols) {
  data_subset <- dplyr::select(data, {{cols}})
  
  args_as_character_vector <- colnames(data_subset)
  
  args_as_character_vector
}

fun_overkill(mtcars, c(mpg, drat))
```

Clearly, this cannot be the best way, and it does not generalise to a situation where my vector argument doesn't represent column names.

I suspect `{rlang}` may have the answer but there are so many choices and I do not understand the terminology.

A situation where this could be useful is in creating a model formula, as you can use `as.formula` on a string, which you create from the character vector:

```
rhs <- paste(fun_overkill(mtcars, c(mpg, drat)), collapse = " + ")
lhs <- "~ "
as.formula(paste0(lhs, rhs))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to capture the `cols` variables of an expression with `enexpr()` (`enquo()` would work too), and then get the arguments from the expression with `call_args()`. These are now a list of symbols, so you need to loop over them to make them characters with `as_string()`.

```r
library(rlang)

fun <- function(data, cols) {
  vars <- call_args(enexpr(cols))
  vapply(vars, as_string, character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}

(fun(mtcars, c(mpg, drat)))
#> [1] "mpg"  "drat"


rhs <- paste(fun(mtcars, c(mpg, drat)), collapse = " + ")
lhs <- "~ "
as.formula(paste0(lhs, rhs))
#> ~mpg + drat
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

To be fair, the `data` argument isn't needed at all here. It's just there because it was there in your example.

Comment: Hi, I am so glad to see you here, I remember a couple months ago you helped me with that `geom_hurricane` extension I wrote for `ggplot2` and I was amazed by your knowledge in data visualization. So I thought I would reach out again and wish you the very best of luck.

Comment: Great answer - thanks for your help and really quick response!

Comment: I have a follow up question teunbrand. When using `call_args` on a single value you get the following error `Error: 'call' must be a quoted call`. Do you know why this is/how I might generalise your function to the single-value case?